# Is there a way to specify a default configuration set on Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase-authentication, amazon-ses

I currently am using Firebase Authentication and am using Amazon SES as the SMTP server to send Firebase emails such as email verification, forgot password, etc.

I also currently have a configuration set in Amazon SES that will send delivery, click, bounce, complaint, etc. event data to Amazon Kinesis Firehose which then writes the data to an S3 bucket.

The issue is that an email will not follow the rules of a configuration set in SES unless the configuration set is specified in the header of the specific email. However, this is not possible due to limited customization in Firebase settings.

Is there any way to specify a default configuration set that all emails should use (so that I don't need to specify anything in the email headers)? Or is there another way I can get around this issue?

Comment: Michael, did you figure out how to choose a default SES Configuration Set so that your SMTP emails didn't need a custom header? I want that too because I want to be able to set up my Gmail app on iOS to send emails via SES SMTP, and I want those emails to automatically use my main Configuration Set. Thanks.

Comment: to me it looks like there is no default option

Comment: Same on Oct 2020. Only solution I can think is to implement the flow ourselves.
Generate the link in server and send it through AWS SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your email sending domian in SES console, Once the email domian is verified by adding relevant TXT record set in your hosted zone of your domain server.
You can configure notification sub section from SES. to notify, This would peform the action at the domain name level, no need to set the configuration set name in header while sending the email

Answer (score 0):

You can now set the default configuration set from the AWS SES dashboard.

Click on **Verified Identities** in the sidebar -> select the domain of choice -> **Configuration set** tab.